# Reuse controls inside a usercontrol

Tags: wpf, silverlight, mvvm, icommand, relaycommand

I have a UserControl UserControl1 and a button inside the UserControl1. And I have a UserControl1ViewModel that has an ICommand property for the button. Using this command I need to call a method outside(from other VMs or VM of the MainWindow) the VM. What is the best practice for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to examine MVVM lite by Laurent Bugnion http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/getstarted/

This is a lightweight toolkit for helping enforce mvvm concepts.  In it, every viewmodel is a static member in a ViewModelLocator class.  So for instance, in your command you could do something like this.

```
ViewModelLocator.MainViewModel.MainContent = NewContent;
```

You can totally do this without mvvm lite, but using it really helps speed up the learning curve and enforce modularity.

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely looking to implement the Mediator pattern to handle the communication between two viewmodels.

Another SO question along the same vein is:
[mvvm-view-model-view-model-communications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474768/mvvm-view-model-view-model-communications)

Comment: I understand the mediator pattern. But I'm confused on how will I allow external handler for the command.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using Controllers for the mediation between the ViewModels. **[The WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)** shows how this works.